# What regex could I use to extract a body of XML text from a body of unformatted text?

Tags: .net, regex

Let's say I have the following body of text:

```
Call me Ishmael. Some years ago- never mind how long precisely- having little 
or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I 
thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. It is  
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RootElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <ChildElement />
   <ChildElement />
</RootElement>
a way I have of driving off the spleen and regulating the circulation. Whenever  
I find myself growing grim about the mouth; whenever it is a damp, drizzly 
November in my soul;
```

What regex could I use that would return to me the XML embedding in the string?

*NOTE: I can assume that `<RootElement>` and `</RootElement>` will always have the same name.*

Comment: Can you assume that there will be no nested element named `RootElement`?

Comment: @SLaks yes, I can make that assumption

Comment: And can you assume that the proza never contains RootElement? Any books about XML in your library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the root element will always be  `<RootElement ...>` and that there will never be a nested `<RootElement>` tag, you can do it like this:

```
\<\?xml .+?\</RootElement\>
```

This regex will lazily match all text between `<?xml` and `</RootElement>`.

Comment: \<\?xml[^>]*\?>\s*<RootElement\s+.+?\</RootElement\> seems safer, just in case there is another \<\?xml in there, but generally xml and regexps don't mix too well.

Comment: @Radomir I don't intend to *parse* the xml with regex.  I just want to extract the XML out so that I can feed it into an XML parser.

Comment: Yes, that's why I deleted my initial answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I understand that the root element will not always be called `RootElement`, so you can use

```
<\?xml[^>]+>\s*<\s*(\w+).*?<\s*/\s*\1>
```

using `RegexOptions.SingleLine`. This will take the first tag name after the opening ´` tag and capture everything until the matching tag.

In C#:

```
resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"<\?xml[^>]+>\s*<\s*(\w+).*?<\s*/\s*\1>", RegexOptions.Singleline).Value;
```